# "invalid signature length" when trying to verify signature

Tags: signature, hash, keccak, verify

I'm using the entire source code to sign and verify messages from https://solidity-by-example.org/signature/ on Remix. But when I go through the process of running the functions `getMessageHash`, `getEthSignedMessageHash` and `verify`, I get the error `The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by the contract: "invalid signature length".`

Apparently, the signed message I got was `0x4858bec21b9698724d16a3c29708621163e863c336c9ddd2f79b19bc3b699729` which is 67 chars long, not 65. So, I went to remove the `0x` in front but I get a new error `Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value`

Below is the full src code.

> ```
> // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
> pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
>
> /* Signature Verification
>
> How to Sign and Verify
> # Signing
> 1. Create message to sign
> 2. Hash the message
> 3. Sign the hash (off chain, keep your private key secret)
>
> # Verify
> 1. Recreate hash from the original message
> 2. Recover signer from signature and hash
> 3. Compare recovered signer to claimed signer
> */
>
> contract VerifySignature {
>     /* 1. Unlock MetaMask account
>     ethereum.enable()
>     */
>
>     /* 2. Get message hash to sign
>     getMessageHash(
>         0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C,
>         123,
>         "coffee and donuts",
>         1
>     )
>
>     hash = "0xcf36ac4f97dc10d91fc2cbb20d718e94a8cbfe0f82eaedc6a4aa38946fb797cd"
>     */
>     function getMessageHash(
>         address _to,
>         uint _amount,
>         string memory _message,
>         uint _nonce
>     ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
>         return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_to, _amount, _message, _nonce));
>     }
>
>     /* 3. Sign message hash
>     # using browser
>     account = "copy paste account of signer here"
>     ethereum.request({ method: "personal_sign", params: [account, hash]}).then(console.log)
>
>     # using web3
>     web3.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount, console.log)
>
>     Signature will be different for different accounts
>     0x993dab3dd91f5c6dc28e17439be475478f5635c92a56e17e82349d3fb2f166196f466c0b4e0c146f285204f0dcb13e5ae67bc33f4b888ec32dfe0a063e8f3f781b
>     */
>     function getEthSignedMessageHash(
>         bytes32 _messageHash
>     ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
>         /*
>         Signature is produced by signing a keccak256 hash with the following format:
>         "\x19Ethereum Signed Message\n" + len(msg) + msg
>         */
>         return
>             keccak256(
>                 abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _messageHash)
>             );
>     }
>
>     /* 4. Verify signature
>     signer = 0xB273216C05A8c0D4F0a4Dd0d7Bae1D2EfFE636dd
>     to = 0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C
>     amount = 123
>     message = "coffee and donuts"
>     nonce = 1
>     signature =
>         0x993dab3dd91f5c6dc28e17439be475478f5635c92a56e17e82349d3fb2f166196f466c0b4e0c146f285204f0dcb13e5ae67bc33f4b888ec32dfe0a063e8f3f781b
>     */
>     function verify(
>         address _signer,
>         address _to,
>         uint _amount,
>         string memory _message,
>         uint _nonce,
>         bytes memory signature
>     ) public pure returns (bool) {
>         bytes32 messageHash = getMessageHash(_to, _amount, _message, _nonce);
>         bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = getEthSignedMessageHash(messageHash);
>
>         return recoverSigner(ethSignedMessageHash, signature) == _signer;
>     }
>
>     function recoverSigner(
>         bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash,
>         bytes memory _signature
>     ) public pure returns (address) {
>         (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = splitSignature(_signature);
>
>         return ecrecover(_ethSignedMessageHash, v, r, s);
>     }
>
>     function splitSignature(
>         bytes memory sig
>     ) public pure returns (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) {
>         require(sig.length == 65, "invalid signature length");
>
>         assembly {
>             /*
>             First 32 bytes stores the length of the signature
>
>             add(sig, 32) = pointer of sig + 32
>             effectively, skips first 32 bytes of signature
>
>             mload(p) loads next 32 bytes starting at the memory address p into memory
>             */
>
>             // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
>             r := mload(add(sig, 32))
>             // second 32 bytes
>             s := mload(add(sig, 64))
>             // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
>             v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
>         }
>
>         // implicitly return (r, s, v)
>     }
> }
> ```

You may test out the entire code in [Remix here](https://remix.ethereum.org/?#code=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&lang=en&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.18%20commit.87f61d96.js).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and then I tried the following:

1. Get your message hash from the `getMessageHash` function
2. Use Remix to sign the message hash (using the icon next to your address)
3. Notice Remix returns both a HASH and SIGNATURE

It turns out I was getting the HASH back from the `getEthSignedMessageHash` function and then trying to use that as the SIGNATURE required by the `verify` function.